# install.packages verbose output suggests packages install was successful when it wasn't

Tags: r

I'm trying to install a package with:

```
install.packages(
  'rJava',
  repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', 
  lib = './lib', 
  quiet = FALSE, 
  verbose = TRUE
  )
```

The above command is in a script that is executed by Rscript.

The output is

```
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 656615 bytes (641 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 641 Kb

foundpkgs: rJava, /tmp/RtmpBRe4qd/downloaded_packages/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz
files: /tmp/RtmpBRe4qd/downloaded_packages/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz

1): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/home/vagrant/examples/lib' /tmp/RtmpBRe4qd/downloaded_packages/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz'

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBRe4qd/downloaded_packages’
```

However, if the lib folder is empty:

```
$ ls lib/
[empty]
```

Why is CMD INSTALL reporting that it succeeded when it hasn't?  If I run the CMD INSTALL manually myself, the installation succeeds:

```
$ R CMD INSTALL -l '/home/vagrant/examples/BigR/lib' /tmp/RtmpBRe4qd/downloaded_packages/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz
* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rJava)
```

After this, the lib folder now has the package:

```
$ ls -l lib/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 10 vagrant vagrant 4096 Mar 16 09:37 rJava
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to use the latest version of R as I was using an old version installed by Ubuntu precise package manager.